# How I can determine the number of integral solutions of the equation of the elliptic curve?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves

Is there a general law to determine how many integral solutions  of the

Equation of  the form (elliptic curve):

> $y²=x^{3}+ax+b,\ \ \ a,b \in \Bbb R$.

Thank you for any help .

Comment: This is in general a difficult problem, see this mathoverflow question http://mathoverflow.net/questions/7907/how-to-find-all-integer-points-on-an-elliptic-curve

Comment: I acrossed this question in my mind after reading a paper about integral point , i saw it's  easy for predicting the numbers of  integral solutions  of equation EC